Sass override with rollup
I have two scss files
fileA:
body {
   background-color: pink;
}

fileB:
body {
   background-color: green;
}

these two files are importet in my JS file:
import './fileA.scss';
import './fileB.scss'

My expectation is that fileB overwrites the background deklaration from fileA to green.
But on my bundled output file I get:
body{background-color:pink;background-color:green}

So my question is: Is there a possibility to overwrite a previos declaration in Sass?
For my rollup config i use:

rollup
rollup-plugin-styler
sass

